# what is the purpose of this statement in UNIX if [['hostname'='bob']]

Tags: unix, output

what is the **purpose of the statement** in unix
the above code
whether it is for checking to see whether the host name is bob
or
changing the hostname to bob or what else

Comment: Not sure whether it is the formatting on the text in the post but as it is, the if statement is checking if the literal "hostname" equals the literal "bob"

Comment: Please [edit] your question and copy&paste the code to the text of the question and format it as code. (You can use the `{}` tool of the editor field.)

Answer (score 0):

The script is performing a string quality check on the output of the hostname command against the string bob. Checking to see whether the hostname is bob.

Comment: There seems to be a typo in `string quality check`.

Answer (score 0):

changing the hostname to bob and checking if the command is successfull